# function in class not counting values from each part of class python

Tags: python, class

I am making a Blackjack simulation game and have made classes for the players, the hands, and the cards. I use this function in the Card Class to get the values for each card.

```
def values(self,rank):
    if self.rank == 'Ace':
        return 11
    elif self.rank == 'Jack' or self.rank == 'Queen' or self.rank == 'King':
        return 10
    else:
        return int(self.rank)
```

and use this function in the Player Hand Class to total the values of each hand.

```
def handValue(self,rank,value):
        value = value + card.values(card.rank)
        return value
```

I call the function like this:

```
print player1Hand.handValue(card.rank)
```

I call the function after each card is added the the player hand class. When I try to get the values of a hand, the handValue function will return only the value of the second card. 'value' is set to 0 once right before I call the handValue function for the first time and the cards going into the hand are from a queue, each card being named 'card' (could be issue but I'm not sure how I would solve that)

The card gets added to the players hand like this:

```
value = 0
card = deck.dequeue()       #takes a card from a queue (the deck)
player1Hand.addCard(card)       #adds it to the hand
player1Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)      #tries to get value
```

Here is the whole code:

```
import random
import time

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.items)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)



class Player:

    def __init__(self,balance,name,bet):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.bet = bet

    def __repr__(self):
        return name, str(balance), str(bet)

    def name(self,name):
        self.name = name
        return name

    def balance(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        return balance

    def bet(self, bet):
        self.bet = bet
        return bet

    def makeBet(self, balance,bet):
        balance = balance - bet
        return self.balance

    def winMoney(self,balance):
        balance = balance * 2

    def hit(self):
        print "Hitting..."
        self.add_Card(self.deck.addCard())

        return self.hand

    def stand(self):
        print name, 'stands'

    def check_bust(self):
        if self.get_value() > 21:
            self.isBust = True
            print "%s busts!" % self.name
        else:
            self.stand()

    def newBet(bet,self):
        self.bet = bet * 2
        return self.bet

balance = 1000 
bet = 100
name = 'player1'
player1 = Player('player1', balance, bet)
player1.makeBet(balance,bet)
name = 'player2'  
player2 = Player('player2', balance, bet)
player2.makeBet(balance,bet)  
name = 'player3'
player3 = Player('player3', balance, bet)
player3.makeBet(balance,bet)
name = 'dealer'
dealer = Player('Dealer', 1300000000, bet) 



class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} of {1}'.format(self.rank, self.suit)   

    def getRank(self,rank):
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self,suit):
        return self.suit

    def values(self):
        if self.rank == 'Ace':
            return 11
        elif self.rank in ('Jack', 'Queen', 'King'):
            return 10
        else:
            return int(self.rank)

class Hand:
    def __init__(self,hand,name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = []

        self.hidden = False

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.hidden == True:
            return '[X]'
        else:
            return '%s\n%s\n\n=====================\n' % (self.name, self.hand)

    def name(self,name):
        self.name = name
        return name

    def hand(self,hand):
        self.hand = hand
        return hand

    def hideCard(self):
        self.hidden = True    

    def addCard(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
        return self.hand

    def handValue(self,rank,value):
        value = value + card.values()
        return value

def shuffle_deck():
    global cards
    cards = []
    for i in range(8): #8 times for 8 decks
        for suit in ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']: 
            for rank in ['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']:
                card = Card(rank,suit)
                cards.append(card)

    random.shuffle(cards) #shuffles cards
    return cards #returns the cards in a list


shuffle_deck()
cut = random.randint(0,416) #cuts deck in random spot
for i in range(cut):
    cards.pop(0)


deck = Queue()
for i in range(len(cards)):
    deck.enqueue(cards[0])
    cards.pop(0)


print 'Each player will start off with $1000, the maximum bets can be $1000 and the minimum bet can be $5.'
#deal cards


import PlayerClass
print 'Each player must make a bet, starting with player 1.' 

player1.makeBet(balance,bet)
print 'Player 1 bet $', player1.bet 

player2.makeBet(balance,bet)
print 'Player 2 bet $', player2.bet

player3.makeBet(balance,bet)
print 'Player 3 bet $', player3.bet



player1Hand = Hand('Player1 Hand:', [])
player2Hand = Hand('Player2 Hand:', [])
player3Hand = Hand('Player3 Hand:', [])
dealerHand = Hand('Dealer Hand:', [])

value = 0
card = deck.dequeue()
player1Hand.addCard(card)
player1Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)
card = deck.dequeue()
player2Hand.addCard(card)
player2Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)
card = deck.dequeue()
player3Hand.addCard(card)
player3Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)
card = deck.dequeue()
dealerHand.addCard(card)
card = deck.dequeue()
player1Hand.addCard(card)
print 'Player 1 Value: ', player1Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)
card = deck.dequeue()
player2Hand.addCard(card)
print 'Player 2 Value:', player2Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)
card = deck.dequeue()
player3Hand.addCard(card)
print 'Player 3 Value:', player3Hand.handValue(card.rank,value)
card = deck.dequeue()
dealerHand.addCard(card)


print 'Player 1:', player1Hand
print 'Player 2:', player2Hand
print 'Player 3:', player3Hand
print 'dealer:', dealerHand


#Player 1 Turn
print 'Player 1 Turn: Hit or Stand'


if player1Hand.handValue(card.rank,value) <= 5: 
    player1.stand()
else:
    player1.hit()
    check_bust()
```

I understand the end of the code will not work at the end, this is as far as I have gotten

Comment: Where does your `Player` instance obtain the `card` property in the `handValue()` method?

Comment: Why does `values()` take a rank it never uses?  This is your problem, as the code shown will never total the actual card.

Comment: Rank is the value of the card. (3, Jack, Queen, Ace) so it needs that to determine if the card value should be 10 or 11 in cases of jacks, queens, kings or aces

Comment: You're constantly mixing global variables, instance variables and local variables so much so that it's hard to discern your intention from your code... Try [`rubber ducking`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) your code first.

Comment: @StephenRauch , what can I do to fix this? I do not really understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: It would help if I could see more code.  But I will post a correct routine in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing quite a few different concepts of how to represent data.

In the case of the card values, there are two ways your could do your `values()` routine.  First you should call it `value()` since it represents the value of only one card.  Then if `rank` is not a property of the card (it should be), but if it isn't, you can do a static method like:

```
@staticmethod
def value(rank):
    if rank == 'Ace':
        return 11
    elif rank in ('Jack', 'Queen', 'King'):
        return 10
    else:
        return int(rank)
```

If `value()` is a property of the card (it should be) then `value()` can be:

```
def value(self):
    if self.rank == 'Ace':
        return 11
    elif self.rank in ('Jack', 'Queen', 'King'):
        return 10
    else:
        return int(self.rank)
```

Note the difference between these two routines.  In the first case the object represented by `self` has no meaning and is not passed.  In the second case, `rank` is an attribute of the object (the card) and does not need to be passed as it will be accesses through `self`

Either of these can be made to work, but the second would be preferred.

#### Update after seeing more code:

Here is a complete `Card()` and a `Hand.value` to calculate the value of a entire hand.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self._rank = rank
        self._suit = suit
        self._value = self.rank_value(rank)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} of {1}'.format(self._rank, self._suit)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Card({0}, {1}'.format(self._rank, self._suit)

    @property
    def rank(self):
        return self._rank

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self._suit

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
        
    @staticmethod
    def rank_value(rank):
        if rank == 'Ace':
            return 11
        elif rank in ('Jack', 'Queen', 'King'):
            return 10
        else:
            return int(rank)

class Hand:

    @property
    def value(self):
        return sum(card.value for card in self.hand)
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I will post my whole code above.

Comment: @josh, so there is a lot more code, but you have made no effort to look at what I have already done, and apply it to the other code.  Your code needs much work.  Try to think about what these various things represent, and then consider how and when they would be read/set/updated.  Then write routines do those things. Then write code to use the objects to play the game.  I will update shortly with a complete `Card()` and how best to value a hand, but the rest will up to you...